# Is it possible to Swap Symbols Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Flash has a feature in which you can swap a symbol with another one from the library. Would it be possible to do this, in Actionscript code, without using bitmap or something like that?
For my project, I want the character's bottom half to disappear when he enters water, along with registration point changing.

Comment: I don't know if you can swap symbols but why not just remove one display object and replace it with another? That should be pretty straight forward. Something like `landChar.parent.addChild(waterChar)` and then `landChar.parent.removeChild(landChar)`

Comment: I dont use the child function much, can you explain how I would do this? Where would I put waterChar? Do I put it in my library?

Comment: `waterChar` and `landChar` are just variables that refer to instances of a class. They can either be created in the IDE or at runtime. If in the IDE then these are the linkage names, I think (I don't work in the IDE much)

Comment: If it's a MovieClip you could also just go to frame 2 and have frame 2 be the character in water

Answer (score 0):

Does the water have alpha transparency? if so you could make an overlay behind the water but in front of the character so that you can't see its bottom half when its dropped into water, If not just put the character on the layer below the water, as for changing the registration point, that is a little more difficult as it would mean you need to move the movieclip within another movieclip (say you had a graphic for the character and had that inside a container movieclip with its registration on the characters head) you would have to use

```
container.character.y = 55;
```

for example to make the registration point shift on the main character, bearing in mind that you will have to make sure that both the container and the character have instance names assigned to them.

**EDIT**
As to your other question, is it possible to swap symbols the answer is yes, by setting the symbol of your character to have an instance name and exported on first frame, you can call it in and out through Actionscript through:

```
container.addChild(character);
```

Or:

```
container.removeChild(character);
```

This will allow you to remove or add the different symbols this link for more details.

[Adding Symbols from Document](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/components/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7ff3.html)

Comment: Yeah, I think a foreground would be easiest, but ima try to use a child because that would be less code